# jquery serialize method not working on form

Tags: forms, jquery, jqueryform

I am trying to submit a form using jquery ajax.

```
<form id="from_cts" action="#" method="post">
    <div>
      <div class="">
          <textarea id="post_dis_contents" name="" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
          <input id="post_dis" type="button" value="Post" />
      </div>
    </div>
</form>​
```

and my jq code is this:

```
$(function() {
  $("#post_dis").click(function() {
    var cts = $("#post_dis_contents").val();
    if (cts) {
        var p = $("#from_cts").serialize();
        //var k = $('#from_cts').find('textarea').serialize();
        alert(p);

    } else {
        alert('null');
    }
 });
});​
```

it just simply contains a textarea there, and i try to alert its value, but nothing there, then I remove all the div elements , still nothing.

Could you please give me some advice, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give name to your `textarea` it will work.

```
<textarea id="post_dis_contents" name="textarea1" cols="" rows=""></textarea>
```

Comment: thanks Chinmayee, i got it. if i don't have a name, jq cannot transform it a map. thanks.